# Dom xpath get first anchor href from html

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is the HTML:

```
<article class="module_article featured">
    <a title="Exclusive: Strictly's Vincent Simone welcomes baby boy" href="h/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/"><h1 class="article_title">Exclusive: Strictly's Vincent Simone welcomes baby boy</h1></a>        <a href="/healthandbeauty/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/">
        <img src="/imagenes/portadas/1-40-vincent-s.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="/healthandbeauty/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/">
        <img src="/imagenes/portadas/1-40-vincent-s.jpg">
    </a>
    <p>HELLO! Online can exclusively reveal that&nbsp;Strictly Come Dancing professional Vincent...</p>
</article>
<article class="module_article featured">
    <a title="Exclusive: Strictly's Vincent Simone welcomes baby boy" href="h/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/"><h1 class="article_title">Exclusive: Strictly's Vincent Simone welcomes baby boy</h1></a>        <a href="/healthandbeauty/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/">
        <img src="/imagenes/portadas/1-40-vincent-s.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="/healthandbeauty/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/">
        <img src="/imagenes/portadas/1-40-vincent-s.jpg">
    </a>
    <p>HELLO! Online can exclusively reveal that&nbsp;Strictly Come Dancing professional Vincent...</p>
</article>
```

Here is my XPATH:

```
$articleLinks   = $finder->query('article[contains(@class,"module_article")]//@href');
```

As you can see, its grabbing both `hrefs`. I need the first one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **XPATH** expression :

```
(/article[contains(@class,"module_article")]//@href)[1]
```

**output :**

```
h/mother-and-baby/2013091914634/vincent-simone-baby-boy-born/
```

**Update(as per the last edit)**

```
/article[contains(@class,"module_article")]/a[1]/@href
```

**DEMO Example:**

```xml
<foo>
  <a href='#1'>1</a>
  <bar>
  <a href='#2'>2</a>
  </bar>
</foo>
<foo>
  <a href='#3'>3</a>
  <baz> <a href='#4'>4</a> </baz>
</foo>
```

**XPATH**

```xpath
/foo/a[1]/@href
```

**output:**

```
#1
#3
```

Comment: I updated my question. I need all the articles first hrefs. this only gives me the first one

Comment: Note that if classes exist like `module_article_header`, and it's NOT something you want to match, `contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " module_article ")` is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the first `<a>` with the `href`:

```
$finder->query('article[contains(@class,"module_article")]/a[1]/@href')
```